Debian package vs ros-XXXXX-package in depends and LD_LIBRARY_PATH warnings
My first post here, excuse me if this isn’t the correct place.
When I build my project, I rely upon a huge number of depends.
It appears that some of those depends are then dependant upon the Ubuntu based package of urdfdom and associated packages, rather than the ros-humble-urdfdom equivalent.
I’m kind of new to this whole thing, but I suspect that this is the cause of  CMake emitting warnings about LD_LIBRARY_PATH having two possible solutions:
/opt/ros/humble/lib/, or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
My question is - how can I prevent this from happening ?
Should I submit an issue to the offending package maintainer - which I suspect is somehow related to the pinocchio package - I’mnot pointing fingers, my analysis could be totally incorrect - I’m new to this !
